# Creating ArcSDE feature class in MS SQL Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, sql-server

Unfortunately I am totally dumb when it comes to programming, and very new to databases (mainly because I studied geography), so :

I have a Microsoft SQL Database Server, and a ArcSDE geodatabase. I made a view in SQL Server Manager, which I can see it in my geodatabase (in ArcCatalog), as a table. Which is great. But I also need the geographic information not just the data from the tables.

So how can I create a feature class in my geodatabase from a view that I created in SQL Server Manager. I did select the "shape" field, but sadly it's not that simple:P

I use: Microsoft SQL Server 2008, ArcGIS 10.0, ArcGIS Server 10.

Comment: Shapefile is a file format for storing spatial data. And you need to create/register column with spatial data in your database. There is no such term as "shapefile in geodatabase". Of course you can store shapefile as a BLOB in DB but I think this is really not what you want to do... If I am right then consider correcting your topic name.

Comment: Indeed. I was talking about SDE feature class. My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your view and spatial column in SDE.

There are two good help topics regarding this question:

1. [Example: Creating a spatial view in SQL Server using SQL and registering it](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_spatial_view_in_SQL_Server_using_SQL/002q000000r3000000/)
2. [Example: Creating a spatial view in SQL Server using the sdetable command](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_spatial_view_in_SQL_Server_using_sdetable/002q000000r5000000/)